# get value from array with std object (php)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

my code in PHP :

```
    $stuff = array($this->complaint_model->get_reply($id)->result());

    print_r($stuff);
```

result :

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [id_customer] => 21 
            [id_complaint] => 2 
            [id] => 4 
            [nama_customer] => Muhammad Bima Zehansyah 
            [from] => Admin 
            [balasan] => coba update 
         ) 
     ) 
)
```

my question is , how to get value [nama_customer] ? thx before guys

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
$stuff = array($this->complaint_model->get_reply($id)->result());
echo $stuffVal = $stuff[0][0]->nama_customer;
```

Comment: $stuffVal is absolutely not necessary

Comment: well played bro!

Answer (score 0):

Get the value like this

```
$stuff[0][0]->nama_customer
```

Here you have **multidimensional array object** that's why you need to first Travers two array like `$stuff[0][0]` and then the object like `$stuff[0][0]->nama_customer`

Comment: thx bro for share !!

Comment: you are welcome and close your question by accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not need to put the result into additional `array` and it would be wise to check if the result is not empty.
 So you just take a first item from your result (which is an object) and call the parameter `nama_customer`

```
$stuff = $this->complaint_model->get_reply($id)->result();
if (!empty($stuff[0]))
    echo $stuff[0]->nama_customer;
```

Comment: nice answer bro!! good job